# Преобразование к базовому классу

Tags: c++, ооп

Доброго времени суток
Никак не получается разобраться с одним примером

```
void fnc();

class CLASS1
{
public:
    int r;
};

class CLASS2 : private CLASS1
{
    friend void fnc();
};

class CLASS3 : public CLASS2
{
};

void fnc()
{
    CLASS3 cl3;
    CLASS1 cl1;
    cl1 = cl3;
}

int main()
{}
```

Ошибок компиляции на VS2008 здесь никаких нет, однако если CLASS3 будет наследоваться не как public, а как protected, появляется ошибка, что преобразование недоступно. Убрать friend - тоже недоступно. В книге Липпмана написано, что оно доступно, если можно обратиться к public полю класса, в который идет преобразование, однако в CLASS3 базовый класс (CLASS1) недоступен (т.к. CLASS2 наследует private), а преобразование есть. Как friend влияет на это и вообще, как в такой ситуации компилятор определяет, доступно преобразование или нет?

С уважением, Виктор

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- В строке `cl1 = cl3` у вас выполняется вызов оператора присваивания.

> Поскольку для `CLASS1` компилятор автоматически сгенерировал оператор присваивания, принимающий аргумент типа `const CLASS1 &`, то в вашем примере строка `cl1 = cl3` приводит к вызову `CLASS1::operator=(const CLASS1 &)`.

- Далее, компилятор пытается подставить объект типа `CLASS3` в вызов `CLASS1::operator=(const CLASS1 &)`.

> - Поскольку этот вызов происходит в пределах функции `fnc,` которая помечена как `friend` в классе `CLASS2,` то вся цепочка преобразований типов `CLASS3 -> CLASS2 -> CLASS1` **доступна** в пределах этой функции.
> - Соответственно, осуществимо преобразование `'const CLASS3 &` -> `const CLASS1 &',` поэтому этот код не приводит к ошибке компиляции.
> - См. также **https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5128908/c-type-conversion-faq**

Comment: Только не конструктор копирования, а оператор присваивания.

Comment: @atwice Да, конечно, дело к вечеру `:)` Спасибо.

Comment: Спасибо. Т.е. получается, что раз напрямую не преобразуется, то компилятор делает преобразование через CLASS2, в котором есть friend? Но если так, то он мог бы сделать это и без friend, так как CLASS3 видит public 2 класса, а тот видит public 1-го
С другой стороны, если CLASS3 будет наследовать как protected или private, будет ошибка, хотя fnc по-прежнему friend второго класса и, как вы сказали, цепочка преобразований доступна в fnc
Я просто логику не могу понять ) Объясните, пожалуйста, по пунктам, какие примерно шаги предпринимает компилятор, чтобы определить, доступно преобразование или не